# Precomputed distances for spectral clustering with scikit-learn

Tags: python-2.7, scikit-learn

I'm struggling to make sense of the spectral clustering documentation [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.SpectralClustering.html).

Specifically.

> If you have an affinity matrix, such as a distance matrix, for which 0 means identical elements, and high values means very dissimilar elements, it can be transformed in a similarity matrix that is well suited for the algorithm by applying the Gaussian (RBF, heat) kernel:
>   `np.exp(- X ** 2 / (2. * delta ** 2))`

For my data, I have a complete distance matrix of size `(n_samples, n_samples)` where large entries represent dissimilar pairs, small values represent similar pairs and zero represents identical entries. (I.e. the only zeros are along the diagonal).

So all I need to do is build the `SpectralClustering` object with `affinity = "precomputed"` and then pass the transformed distance matrix to `fit_predict`.

I'm stuck on the suggested transformation equation. `np.exp(- X ** 2 / (2. * delta ** 2))`.

What is `X` here? The `(n_samples, n_samples)` distance matrix?

If so, what is `delta`. Is it just `X.max()-X.min()`?

Calling `np.exp(- X ** 2 / (2. * (X.max()-X.min()) ** 2))` seems to do the right thing. I.e. big entries become relatively small, and small entries relatively big, with all the entries between 0 and 1. The diagonal is all 1's, which makes sense, since each point is most affine with itself.

But I'm worried. I think if the author had wanted me to use `np.exp(- X ** 2 / (2. * (X.max()-X.min()) ** 2))` he would have told me to use just that, instead of throwing `delta` in there.

So I guess my question is just this. What's `delta`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `X` in this case is the matrix of distances. `delta` is a scale parameter that you can tune as you wish. It controls the "tightness", so to speak, of the distance/similarity relation, in the sense that a small delta increases the relative dissimmilarity of faraway points.

Notice that `delta` is proportional to the inverse of the `gamma` parameter of the RBF kernel, mentioned earlier in the doc link you give: both are free parameters which can be used to tune the clustering results.

Comment: Is there a suggested value for `delta`? Is it common to use `X.max()-X.min()`?

Comment: The best choice for ``delta`` is entirely dependent on your data. Too large, and faraway points will be considered adjacent. Too small, and adjacent points will be considered far away. You'll probably want to make it some multiple of your data range or standard deviation and tune it until you get good results.

Comment: Well, for the purpose I'm using it for I really don't have the ability to tune it. I need a formula that for `delta` based on `X` that is likely to do well. Based on this discussion, I'll just use `X.max()-X.min()`. I'm going to hold off on awarding you the answer for a day to see if someone comes by with a best-practices default for `delta. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Selecting the kernel width is a hyperparameter optimization, meaning you need some quantitative measure of how "good" your results are for a training set, and you vary ``delta`` to optimize this measure. It's actually quite a difficult problem in general, and an active area of research; see for example http://140.123.102.14:8080/reportSys/file/paper/lei/lei_8_paper.pdf I'm sorry to not give you a simpler answer, but to the best of my knowledge a simpler answer does not exist.

Comment: One additional point: the R ``kernlab`` package has a spectral clustering routine with a heuristic for automatically determining this parameter: http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/kernlab/docs/specc There's no information on the reasoning behind the heuristic, and R code generally looks like spaghetti to me, but you may find that useful!

Comment: I think I'd rather put my hand in a blender than study R code, but thanks for the tip.